# How to mock an @Async call in a Repository

Tags: spring, junit5, spring-test

I have created an example using Spring 6(6.0.0-M2 at the moment)/Spring Data JPA, and create a Repository like this.

```java
public interface PostRepository extends JpaRepository<Post, UUID> {

    @Async
    CompletableFuture<List<Post>> readAllBy();
}
```

In the controller testing codes, I try to mock it as general mocking method, failed.

```java
when(this.posts.readAllBy())
    .thenReturn(CompletableFuture.completedFuture(
         List.of(
             Post.builder().title("test").content("content of test1").build(),
             Post.builder().title("test2").content("content of test2").build()
             )
        )
    );
```

When running the tests, I got the following mocking errors:

```sh
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException: 
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
    when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Also, this error might show up because:
1. you stub either of: final/private/equals()/hashCode() methods.
   Those methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified.
   Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
2. inside when() you don't call method on mock but on some other object.
```

The complete testing codes is [here](https://github.com/hantsy/spring6-sandbox/blob/master/async/src/test/java/com/example/demo/web/PostControllerTest.java#L70).

**Update**: If I remove the async config from the test context(that means async is disabled.), it works well.  But how to do when async is enabled?

Comment: You sure `posts` is a mock?

Comment: @BoristheSpider when removing asynconfig in the test context, and mocking a `exectuor` which used in controllers, it will work.

Comment: @BoristheSpider The mock config is [here](https://github.com/hantsy/spring6-sandbox/blob/master/async/src/test/java/com/example/demo/web/TestDataConfig.java).

Comment: Probably proxied. Use `MockBean` on the test instead.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Not used Spring Boot in this example. I think it is a general problem when testing `@Async` .